# How to show that "If cancellation laws hold in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, then $n$ must be prime"

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was  assigned to prove that the following statements are equivalent:

1. $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has no zero divisors.
2. $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is an integral domain.
3. The cancellation laws hold in $\mathbb{Z}_n$
4. $n$ is prime.

For the proof of $(1)\implies (2)$, $(2)\implies (3)$ and $(4)\implies (1)$ I encountered no problem.

I am having a difficulty in proving the implication $3\implies 4$. But I found a counterexample. For instance since $n=4$ is not prime, then we have in $\mathbb{Z}_4$:

$2(3)=2(1)=2$ but $3\neq 1$.

So I assume that the proof is via contradiction.

Here is my attempt:

Let $a\neq 0$ be an element of $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Since cancellation laws hold then

$ab=ac\implies b=c$.

This means that $b\equiv c(mod\ n)$ or $n\mid(b-c)$.

Now suppose $n$ is composite. Then $b-c=kn$ for $k<b-c<n$.

From here, I do not know how to proceed. Is my proof flow correct? If not how can we prove the implication $(3)\implies (4)$.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Is it not enough to say if $n = ab$ and $a \ne n$ then $ab =n \equiv 0 \equiv a*0 \pmod n$ and by cancelation law $b\equiv 0 \pmod n$?

Comment: Yes @fleablood you are right.

Comment: You don't *have* to prove $3\implies 4$. Can prove any $a \implies 4$ and and $3\implies b$.... if any of those are easier... $3\implies 1$ is straight forward: cancelation implies $a;ab=0=a0\implies b=0$. And $4\iff 1$ is not hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, here's a **hint**: suppose that $n$ is not prime, so that $n = st$ with $s,t \geq 1$. Look at this equation modulo $n$.

> Derive a contradiction from the fact that $st \equiv 0 = s \cdot 0\pmod{n}$ but $0 < s \neq n$ and in particular, $n | s$.

Comment: Thank you @Guido A. All clear now. Am I right that ``the contradiction is in the part $t=0$. Since $t>1$ if $n$ is composite?

Comment: Yes, the argument is symmetric with either $s$ or $t$, my idea was that since $st = s0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ then $s = 0$ by cancellation, which would imply $n | s$ and that can't happen. The user fleablood provided a direct version of this argument in the comments, which is a little bit cleaner in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose cancellation holds in $\mathbb Z_n$. Then $ab = 0$ implies $a = 0$ or $b = 0$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb Z_n$. If $n$ were composite, taking $ab = n$ would give a contradiction.